# How can I define the forward URLs (service Id + some path) Spring Zuul chooses when it retrieves the list of registered services from Spring Eureka?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

## Context

I'm developing a proof of concept with Spring Zuul and Eureka. I want Zuul to work as an API Gateway and I want it to discover my microservices registered in Eureka. I want my microservices to be versioned. Zuul, Eureka and each microservice run on their own (I have a separate project for all of them).

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.3 and Spring Cloud Dalston. But I can upgrade, if necessary.

Now, let's say that I have one microservice configured in the following way in the `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: microservice-v1
server:
  port: 11001
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:11000/eureka/
```

This microservice has a `GET /microservice` REST endpoint configured which I can access from the address `http://localhost:11001/microservice`. It runs well and it registers itself with Eureka.

This `ZuulReverseProxy.java` is the main class of my Zuul project:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulReverseProxy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulReverseProxy.class, args);
    }

}
```

Based on the [Spring Cloud Docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy), I have this configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
public class ZuulConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PatternServiceRouteMapper serviceRouteMapper() {
        return new PatternServiceRouteMapper(
                "(?<name>^.+)-(?<version>v.+$)",
                "${version}/${name}");
    }

}
```

And this is the `application.yml` of my Zuul project:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: zuul
server:
  port: 8888
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  strip-prefix: true
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:11000/eureka/
```

Zuul looks into Eureka, gets the list of registered microservices and creates a mapping for each one according to the `PatternServiceRouteMapper` above. I'm not ignoring any services for now.

All of the above, allows Zuul to redirect `http://localhost:8888/api/v1/microservice/microservice` to `http://localhost:11001/microservice`, for example. In a more general way, it redirects anything with the path `/api/v1/microservice/<some-path>` to `http://localhost:11001/<some-path>`

## Question

How can I avoid writing `microservice` twice in the URL, but still be able to request the mapping `/microservice` in the controller of my microservice?

A solution to this problem could be requesting the mapping `/` instead of `/microservice`. But I don't want to do that. The reason is that I'm using [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) and its Codegen to generate interfaces and if I request the mappings without writing a collection name, I feel that my specification is not as good.

I thought of writing a `route` Zuul filter, but I couldn't find a good example. Also, I think that if I could alter the code that handles the moment when Zuul tries to map the Eureka services to a path, that could be a solution.

When not in conjunction with Eureka, Zuul allows to specify an input path and a forward URL with address, port and something else. The same should be possible when specifying a Service Id. Maybe I can modify some code in a way that the routing is still dynamic but that I can add that something else.

Would modifying the classes `SimpleRouteLocator` or `ZuulHandlerMapping` help? or is another class in charge of that dynamic routing? Also what would be the best way of implementing something like this?

## Edit

I realized that when you configure Zuul like this for example:

```
zuul:
  add-proxy-headers: true
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  routes:
    uaa:
      path: /uaa/**
      service-id: oauth-v1
      strip-prefix: false
      sensitive-headers:
```

It does what I want it to do. That `strip-prefix` is different from the global one.

When I configured my Zuul that way, in the log I see:

```
... o.s.c.n.zuul.filters.SimpleRouteLocator  : Matching pattern:/uaa/**
...  : route matched=ZuulProperties.ZuulRoute(id=uaa, path=/uaa/**, serviceId=oauth-v1, url=null, stripPrefix=false, retryable=null, sensitiveHeaders=[], customSensitiveHeaders=true)
```

When Zuul loads the services registered in Eureka, in the log I see

```
.... o.s.c.n.zuul.filters.SimpleRouteLocator  : route matched=ZuulProperties.ZuulRoute(id=v1/microservice, path=/v1/microservice/**, serviceId=microservice-v1, url=null, stripPrefix=true, retryable=null, sensitiveHeaders=[], customSensitiveHeaders=false)
```

The only significant difference is that the latter says `stripPrefix=true` and to solve my problem, it should be `false`.

I think that it should be possible to change that default behaviour somehow...

Comment: The default behavior is pretty inflexible. You'd need to write a custom filter.

Comment: Is there an example you could provide me to try and follow?

Comment: Not exactly what you are doing, but here are some sample filters https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sample-zuul-filters